# Netbeans warning about type cast too strong, but get error if remove cast

Tags: java, netbeans, casting, bytebuffer

Here's the code snippet:

```
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(deleteInfo.size);
    for(int j = 0; j < deleteInfo.size; j++)
      buf.put(j,(byte)'.');
```

Here's the warning on the last line above:

```
Unnecessary cast to byte
```

I agree, but when I remove the cast...

```
  buf.put(j, '.');
```

... here's the error:

```
incompatible types; possible lossy conversion from char to byte
```

I realize that `char` is two bytes in Unicode, so surely this is the reason for the error. In this cast of `char` to `byte`, the warning has no negative implications, since all of my data is ASCII. (I tried using the actual ASCII code for '.'; same results.)

So I can safely ignore the error, but I'd like to deal with this "legitimately" and not just turn off or ignore the warning mechanism.

None of the topics that showed up on the page to submit questions appear to address the problem. Google turned up `getBytes` and `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` returns "UTF-8" without me saying I want to use that encoding, but I can't see how to apply `getBytes("UTF-8")` (or anything else) to `buf`.

How can I code to avoid the warning? Or should I just write it off as a danged-if-I-do-danged-if-I-don't Netbeans quirk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's horrible and cumbersome but you can avoid the cast with:

```
".".getBytes()[0]
```

which is actually exactly what you want. A `char` is actually an `int` in different clothing and you want the low byte of the int - which is what this does.

Comment: Yes, this IS horrible in that it's a ridiculous way to make Netbeans stop whining!! But thanks. I would have NEVER come up with this clever bit. I upvoted you for two reasons: So far it's the only code-based answer (and I learned something!) AND I read your 'notes to self' and discover that YOU, TOO, find people who start--out of the blue--with "So..." to be annoying!! I'm glad I didn't make my post say "SO, here's the code snippet!" But there's no way I would've! Of course, I did eventually say "So I can safely ignore...", but THAT'S OK. I drew a conclusion. (End of preach.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to add code to get rid of the warning.

Open NetBeans and navigate to Tools -> Options -> Editor. Go to the 'Hints' tab, select java and open the 'Standard Javac Warnings' drop-down and uncheck 'Unnecessary Cast' box.

If you are using a Mac instead, then all steps are the same, except for going to 
Tools -> Options go to NetBeans -> Preferences.

Alternatively you can add `@SuppressWarnings("cast")` above the method where you are casting that stuff.

Comment: Right, but, as I said, I didn't want to just ignore it. However, considering that the only other answer contains a "horrible" way to make Netbeans quit whining, this is probably what I'm going to do--turn off the warning. I guess it's perfectly reasonable to turn off a warning that, if left on and followed, leads to an error! It's kind of like the "hint" to invert an 'if'. Take the hint and get the SAME hint! WTH!? That one's off; so's this one as of right ... NOW.

Comment: Changed my mind. Leaving the hint ON, but will ignore. I'm not sure of the implications of what the hint message says: "Reports type casts, which are too strict and casting to a more general type would be sufficient for the actual expression. Sometimes, an instance is casted to a specific subtype, but methods invoked or fields used from the casted instance are actually defined by some supertype. In that case cast to too specific type introduces an unnecessary coupling to the code and **limits its extensibility**." It might one day be good that the hint is still ON.

Comment: @DSlomer64 I just remembered something else you can do, if you just want that warning ignored in a specific section of code. Check out the new edit.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. At least this way there's documentation of something in the code that's not necessarily kosher, even though for all practical purposes the cast is kosher enough. Lotsa hoops to jump through sometimes...

Comment: @BitNinja--Good point. I didn't say what I meant. Here's the 'workaround'.    `byte b = '.' ; buf.put(j,b); `